# Rails Forem installation assistance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, forem

So i'm quite new to rails and such and I've been trying to install this for the past few hours and have been getting the following error when trying to run `rails s`, or if I try to install it with `rails g forem:install`

> /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in
>   `load': /home/forem/config/initializers/session_store.rb:3: syntax
>   error, unexpected ':', expecting $end (SyntaxError) ...sion_store
>   :cookie_store, key: '_forums_session'
>                                 ^
>           from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in
>
> > `load'
> >             from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in`
> >     load_dependency'
> >             from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in
> >     `load'
> >             from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/engine.rb:588
> >             from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/engine.rb:587:in`
> >     each'
> >             from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/engine.rb:587
> >             from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in
> >     `instance_exec'
> >             from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in`
> >     run'
> >             from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in
> >     `run_initializers'
> >             from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in`
> >     each'
> >             from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in
> >     `run_initializers'
> >             from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in`
> >     initialize!'
> >             from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in
> >     `send'
> >             from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in`
> >     method_missing'
> >             from /home/forem/config/environment.rb:5
> >             from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in
> >     `require'
> >             from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in`
> >     require'
> >             from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in
> >     `load_dependency'
> >             from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in`
> >     require'
> >             from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/application.rb:103:in
> >     `require_environment!'
> >             from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands.rb:25
> >             from script/rails:6:in`require'
> >             from script/rails:6

So is there something I'm missing here or...?

The one that I downloaded is this one: `https://github.com/radar/forem.heroku.com`

Comment: what's the content of file : `/home/forem/config/initializers/session_store.r` ?

Comment: It contains:                                                                                                                               `# Be sure to restart your server when you modify this file.

Forums::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_forums_session'

# Use the database for sessions instead of the cookie-based default,
# which shouldn't be used to store highly confidential information
# (create the session table with "rails generate session_migration")
# Forums::Application.config.session_store :active_record_store
`

Comment: What does'ruby -v' say?

Comment: It says `ruby 1.8.7 (2011-06-30 patchlevel 352) [x86_64-linux]`

Answer (score 1):

The error you're getting is due to the fact that you're using the Ruby 1.9+ hash syntax in an older version of Ruby that does not support  it. You need to either upgrade Ruby to 1.9.2 or 1.9.3, or change the second line of session_store.rb file to be:

```
# Be sure to restart your server when you modify this file.
Forums::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, :key => '_forums_session'
```

Comment: Thank you, i'll go ahead and try that

Comment: Right, now i'm getting this: >rails g forem:install
>/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/yaml.rb:56:in `<top (required)>':
>It seems your ruby installation is missing psych (for YAML output).
>To eliminate this warning, please install libyaml and reinstall your >ruby.
>/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord->3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:12>08:in `initialize': could not connect to server: No such file or >directory (PG::Error)
     >   Is the server running locally and accepting
     >   connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?

Comment: That's definitely an unrelated issue. I'd recommend opening a new question for better visibility and to get more eyes on it.

Comment: I think the issue may be because I have done a different instillation of ruby, i'm going to reinstall it.